# Use Map in react to display list of objects

Tags: reactjs, arrays, dictionary, object

I am trying to map through a list of objects and display them but can't figure out how. Below is the code

```
import Minimalist from "../Images/Minimalist.jpg";
import axios from "axios";

const BlogList = () => {
  const [blogList, setBlotList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${"http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog"}`);
        setBlotList(res.data[1]);
        console.log(res.data);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const getBlogList = () => {
    let list = [];
    let result = [];

    blogList.map((blogList) => {
      return list.push();
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-2 align-items-stretch g-4 py-5">
          <div className="col">
            <a href="/">
              <div
                className="card card-cover h-100 overflow-hidden text-bg-dark rounded-4 shadow-lg"
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Minimalist})` }}
              >
                <div className="d-flex flex-column h-100 p-5 pb-3 text-white text-shadow-1">
                  <h3 className="pt-5 mt-5 mb-4 display-6 lh-1 fw-bold">
                    {blogList.title}
                  </h3>
                  <ul className="d-flex list-unstyled mt-auto">
                    <li className="d-flex align-items-center me-3">
                      <svg className="bi me-2" width="1em" height="1em">
                        <use xlinkHref="#geo-fill" />
                      </svg>
                      <small className="badge bg-success-subtle border border-success-subtle text-success-emphasis rounded-pill">
                        Rs. 10000
                      </small>
                    </li>
                    <li className="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <svg className="bi me-2" width="1em" height="1em">
                        <use xlinkHref="#calendar3" />
                      </svg>
                      <small className="badge bg-success-subtle border border-success-subtle text-success-emphasis rounded-pill">
                        20 Days
                      </small>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default BlogList;
```

Please can anyone help. I am able to see only 1 object displayed on the page so I can see all the objects

Please assist how do Use map function in react or if there's anything better so I can get the result

Comment: have you read the docs befote asking a question? https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists